# how to print a value from function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

Have a look at the code in images below:

HTML:

[image]

JS:

[image]

`cartAmt = productDetail.discountedPrice++;` this is not working

`${{cart.cartAmt}}` this value is not shown up

Comment: Can you also share the html code? and your cartAmt appears to be a global variable change that and declare it in controller

Comment: Also I think there is a logical error in  `cartAmt = productDetail.discountedPrice++`. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: And it will be better if you copy and paste the code instead of posting a screenshot

Comment: please check again I have added html code snippet!

Comment: Please add your code as text, not images. A formatting tool is available.

Comment: Please add code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images do not allow us to copy & paste the code/errors for testing. In addition, an image of your code/error does not permit it to be searched based on the code/error contents.  In general, code/errors in text format >>> code/errors as an image >>>>> nothing.  Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code cartAmt is a global variable, add it to scope.

```
// Set cart amount to zero initially
$scope.cartAmt = 0    


$scope.cart= function(){   
    $scope.cartAmt += $scope.event.productDetail.discountedPrice; 
}
```

And in your HTML, you can access it like this:

```
<ins>cartAmt</ins>
```

Also as I mentioned in comments, following line has a logical error.

```
$scope.cartAmt = $scope.event.productDetail.discountedPrice++;
```

You should use:

```
$scope.cartAmt += +$scope.event.productDetail.discountedPrice;
```

Comment: thanks this helped it is not evaluating value                            $scope.cartAmt += $scope.event.productDetail.discountedPrice;                               when I click add cart button instead of doing addition of, for example 700+700, it prints 0700700

Comment: In your product details array the amount is a string.

Comment: Change the amount to number or use `$scope.cartAmt += +$scope.event.productDetail.discountedPrice; `

Comment: thanks that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this my be help. and your question not enough for understand

```
 $scope.cart= function(){   
  cartAmt = $scope.event.productDetail.discountedPrice++; 
 }
```